# Android ScrollView scrolling

Tags: android, scrollview, layout-inflater

I'm working on a project where I have a ScrollView which contains a linearlayout.

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#9e9e9e"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:id="@+id/scrollview_llChatContainer"
            android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llChatContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#cccccc">

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

I'm inflating this linearlayout in my code. The last result looks more like a listView. Here is how I'm inflating the LinearLayout.

```
public void populateMessages(List<Message> messagesList){
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.inc_message_layout, llChatContainer, false);
            imageLoader.displayImage(message.imageuser, (ImageView)messageLayout.findViewById(R.id.imageView));
            }

            if(!message.image.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                imageLoader.displayImage(message.image, (ImageView)messageLayout.findViewById(R.id.rivMsgImageN));
            }

            TextView tv = (TextView)messageLayout.findViewById(R.id.tvMsgTextN);
            tv.setText(message.text);
            llChatContainer.addView(messageLayout);
        }
    }
```

Now when the list is populated, I want the scrollView to scroll to the bottom of the LinearLayout. I have tried two of the ways I found.

```
   scroller.post(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
            scroller.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN); 
        } 
    });

scroller.post(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 
        scroller.scrollTo(0,scroller.getBottom()); 
    } 
});
```

None of the above mentioned solution is working for me. Linearlayout gets populated as expected but the scrollview doesn't even scroll a bit.

Is there any other work-around to get this done?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this is caused by time problem , try to scroll with a little delay , use this code

```
       scroller.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            scroller.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }
    }, 10L);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `scroller.scrollTo(0,linearlayout.getBottom());` or `scroller.scrollTo(0,linearlayout.getHeight());` after `populateMessages()` called. Child of the `ScrollView` is changing it's value not the `ScrollView` itself.